# Expo command not found on Mac OS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I'm getting into react native and working on my first project but when installing the expo cli it seems to install successfully and gives me this message:

```
+ expo-cli@4.1.4
updated 1 package in 104.588s
```

But when actually attempting to use it with `expo init rn-app` it tells me that `-bash: expo: command not found` - I have tried the solution on the other stackoverflow post made about this issue and it didn't solve it for me.

I have also seen that some solutions recommend to edit .bash_profile file but I can't seem to find that file either

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by installing [Volta](https://volta.sh/) then re-installing expo after